# React Native, how to animate a number

Tags: reactjs, react-native, animation

Any advice on how to animate a number? I'm working on an app that will show the user's current points on the home screen. When the screen is focused, I'd like the points to count up from 0 to their current total point value, over a duration of 900ms, rendering the animated value in a Text component.

I've tried a number of things with React Native's Animated API as well as with different options for storing and referencing the state, and nothing has worked for me so far. Anyone done this before or have ideas to help me get unstuck? Thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With ReAnimated 3 you can use a withTiming animation to set a shared value.

Display the value using `react-native-animateable-text`

```
import Animated, {useDerivedValue, useAnimatedProps} from 'react-native-reanimated';
import AnimateableText from 'react-native-animateable-text';

const Score = () => {
  // declare a shared value
  const points = useSharedValue<number>(0);

  // customize the format and display as string
  const animatedText = useDerivedValue(() => `Your score is ${points.value}`);

  // pass it as animated props
  const animatedProps = useAnimatedProps(() => ({
    text: animatedText.value;
  }));

  // stable counting function
  const countTo = useCallback((endValue: number) => {
    points.value = withTiming(endValue, {duration: 900});
  }, [points])

  useFocusEffect(useCallback(() => {  
    const init = () => {

      const endValue = 1000; // get your own endValue, this will count to 1000

      countTo(endValue);
    }

    init().catch(e => {
      if (e instanceof Error) {
        console.error(e.message);
      }
    });

    return () => {
      // start with points at 0, no animation
      points.value = 0;
    }
  },[countTo, points]);

  return (
    <View>
      <AnimateableText
      animatedProps={animatedProps}
      />
    </View>
  ) 
  
}
export default Score
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm new in react you can use React Spring for animating
[examples](https://www.react-spring.dev/examples)
and maybe you need some thing like this
[example](https://codesandbox.io/s/ucvbf)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).